# Login form with Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, forms, authentication, web-scraping, mechanize

I've been trying to write a webscraper in Ruby to scrape from a corporate events data website, and I'm referring to the [Flickr example on the Mechanize docs](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) page:

When I run corp_act_scrape.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
home_page = agent.get("http://www.eventsdata.com/main.php#")

mypage = home_page.form_with(:name => 'loginForm') do |form|
    form.myusrname = ARGV[0]
    form.mypasswrd = ARGV[1]
end.submit

rows = page.css('#recentEventsDiv > div.RecentEventsDisplay > table > tbody > tr')

nextLink = page.link_with(:text => 'Next')
hasNextLink = nextLink?

while page.hasNextLink do
    puts rows
    page = agent.click(page.nextLink)
end
```

I receive the error:

```
corp_act_scrape.rb:9:in `block in <main>': undefined method `myusrname=' for nil:
NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):23:in `form_with'
    from corp_act_scrape.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Copying the Flickr example, it seems that I should be able to enter my username and password as methods, but it doesn't seem to work in practice.  Also, that section of the code is pretty confusing to me.  If you have an alternative method of submitting the form, please also let me know.

Comment: Where you found `:name => 'Login'` ? I mean I am not getting a for name `'Login'`.

Comment: huh, okay.  what are you getting?

Comment: You point me where you got a form name `Login` ?

Comment: sorry, it was actually *loginForm*

Comment: However, I still receive the same error

Comment: You want to login the page.. right ? In the url, you gave no `form` I found having name `loginForm`....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49762/discussion-between-user3103499-and-arup-rakshit)